# When should I use $.getJSON.done() instead of $.getJSON()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if there are any conceptual differences between these two codes:

Code 1:

```
$(function(){ 
  var url = "url";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
  console.log(data);
  })
});
```

Code 2:

```
$(function(){ 
  var url = "url";
  $.getJSON(url).done(function(data){
  console.log(data);
  })
});
```

In which situation the $.getJson().done() method is most relevant ?

Comment: Because they are: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/ If you do not need a promise, use the simpler version

Comment: @mplungjan Is the 'done' handler added inline not itself simply/effectively added to the deferred 'promise'? (In both cases a deferred is returned.) That is, what is the *practical* difference?

Comment: @user2864740 there's little practical difference. The callback argument is simply backward compatibility from before promises were added to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The First one uses a callback function as a second param. This allows you to execute code after the function is completed. Note, you are in a separate function.

The Second also uses a callback function as a promise but it is working different under the hood.

```js
// version one
setTimeout(function() {
  doStuff1();
  doStuff2();
}, 1000)


// version one - callback
function doStuff1() {
  doSomething1("value", function(responce) {
    console.log(responce);
  });
};

function doSomething1(v, cb) {
  if (typeof v === "string") {
    cb(true);
  } else {
    cb(false);
  }
  return false;
}

// note the function will always return false but the callback gets the value you want



// version 2, class with promise callback
// look at the class function and see how it works slightly differently
function doStuff2() {
  var $ = new doSomething2();
  $.Something("value").done(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp)
  });
};

class doSomething2 {
  constructor() {
    this.v = false;
  }

  Something(val) {
    if (typeof val === "string") {
      this.v = true;
    } else {
      this.v = false;
    }
    return this;
  }
  done(cb) {
    return cb(this.v);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of a situation where one must be used instead of the other ?

Comment: Well, the cool thing about version 2 is the ability to use it in a variable. You can set `$.Something("string")` into a variable. `let task1 = $.Something("string");` Then you can continue to do stuff in your application and call `task1.done(fn);` when you are ready to.

Comment: I see. Many thanks for your quick responses.